# Replacing link text on Hide/Show

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure this question will take one of you 3 seconds to answer but I'm stumped. After I have clicked "Enable Tips" the text changes to "Disable Tips" as expected, but after you click "Disable Tips" the text doesn't reset to "Enable Tips" again. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
  // function to toggle tips
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".help").hide();
    document.getElementById("help_trigger").innerHTML = "Enable Tips";
    $("a#help_trigger").click(function(){
    $(".help").toggle("400");
    document.getElementById("help_trigger").innerHTML = "Disable Tips";
    return false;
    });
    });
```

HTML

```
  <a id="help_trigger" href="">Enable Tips</a>             
      <div class="help" style="display: none">something</div>
           <div class="help" style="display: none">something else</div>
```

Comment: Could you also post the HTML ? or better make a demo at jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com ?

Comment: Yeah... what Clyde Lobo said... post the HTML, please

Comment: There we go I just posted it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your click handler, you need to test for the current value and set it to the opposite.  Since you're using jQuery already, you really ought to use it for everything.

```
$(function(){ // short-hand is cleaner, IMO
    $(".help").hide();
    $("#help_trigger")
        .text( "Enable Tips" )
        .click(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $(".help").toggle("400");
            if ($this.text().match(/Disable/i)) {
                $this.text("Enable Tips");
            }
            else {
                $this.text("Disable Tips");
            }
           return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks tvanfosson, I chose your answer as it gives me more scope for the future.

Answer (score 2):

Just put this in place instead of your click function

```
$('a#help_trigger').click(function(){
   if ($(this).html().trim() == 'Disable Tips') {
      $(this).html('Enable Tips');
   } else { 
      $(this).html('Disable Tips');
   }
   return false; 
})
```

This will toggle the value depending on what the current HTML is. Keep in mind that the HTML has to be exact! Otherwise use a variable to check state and switch.

Comment: I'm not sure what the best answer is - yours or tvanfosson's as both work perfectly.

Comment: Both essentially do the same thing, except his uses a regex to match for the word Disable. OP decides :)

Comment: Thanks for your help John but I went with tvanfosson's answer simply because it gives me more scope for future use with the regex.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nT7B3/) OR [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/nT7B3/1/)

```
$("a#help_trigger").toggle(function (){

            $(this).text("Enable Tips");

        }, function(){

            $(this).text("disable Tips ");

        });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nT7B3/1/)