# Show div and change inner content:)

Tags: javascript, jquery, show, hidden

I have simple jquery show and hide, but i need a little help  i have this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

});

</script>
```

And CSS

```
.slidingDiv {
    height:300px;
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    border-bottom:5px solid #3399FF;
}

.show_hide {
    display:none;
}
```

Adn simple Html

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide">Show</a>
<div class="slidingDiv">
Fill this space with really interesting content. <a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a></div>
```

What i need is when someone click on SHOW, the element will open, but, i want when someone clik on SHOW to change SHOW to HIDE when DIV element is opened, and when someone click on HIDE, again to change to SHOW, and the problem is that i am going to have a many hidden elements, how to do that? 
example i will have many slidingDIV on page, but i wnat to open just that that is connected to that a href

Comment: Please choose a better question title so your question can be found by someone with the same problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing link text on Hide/Show](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113532/replacing-link-text-on-hide-show)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});
```

To:

```
 $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();

    if($(this).text() == "Show" ? $(this).text("Hide") : $(this).text("Show"));
 });
```

**Update for your edited question:**

To change just the div that is relevant, go with this this code (gets the next .slidingDiv to the clicked href):

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
     $(this).next(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();

     if($(this).text() == "Show" ? $(this).text("Hide") : $(this).text("Show"));
});
```

You can see this working here: http://jsfiddle.net/EYnhk/

Comment: You can do $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle("fast") or $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle("slow")

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();
        $('.show_hide').click(function(){
            $(".slidingDiv").Toggle();
            if ($('.show_hide').text() == "Show"){
                $('.show_hide').text('hide');
            }else {
                $('.show_hide').text('Show');
            }
        });       
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        if( $(this).html()=="Show"){
            $(this).html("Hide");
        }
        else{
            $(this).html("Show");
        }
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ru6gr/3/)